# Shiny app with navbar and different sidebar

Tags: r, shiny

I'm a former R user but new to Shiny development. I'd like to create a Shiny app with a top navigation bar but I can't seem to understand how I can assing different pages to the top bar links.

I have a currently working bar with three different menus, how can I now create different pages for every menu so that when I click on the bar it opens the different page? If I have several page will the Shiny app be very slow?

For example using the sample code

```
    navbarPage("App Title",
      tabPanel("Plot"),
      tabPanel("Summary"),
      tabPanel("Table")
    )
```

How can I now design different pages?

Edit: code example

```
shinyUI(navbarPage("title",
                   tabPanel("analysis",
                            headerPanel("analysis"),
                                            sidebarPanel("Text"),
                                            mainPanel(textOutput("Text display"))

                            ),
                   navbarMenu("analysis1",
                              tabPanel("Analysis2",
                                       headerPanel("analysis 3"),
                                                       sidebarPanel("Text"),
                                                       mainPanel(tabsetPanel("!",
                                                         tabPanel("1", textOutput("Text display"),
                                                         tabPanel("20", textOutput("Text display100")))))
                                       ),
                              tabPanel("analysis5",
                                       headerPanel("analysis3"),
                                                       sidebarPanel("Text"),
                                                       mainPanel(textOutput("Text display"))))
                              , inverse = T, collapsible = T))
```

Actually the second page doesn't work with also a tabset panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, it is really not that well documented.
You pass the outputs as arguments:

```
tabPanel("text", textOutput("sum"),...)
```

Comment: And if I want a page with a sidebar? Can I pass it after the name of the panel?